# Eichler orders in a certain quaternion algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, galois-representations, division-algebras

Let us consider a totally real number field $K$ such that $[K \colon {\Bbb Q}] = {\mathrm{odd}}$. We shall consider the quaternion algebra $D$ over $K$ such that $D$ splits everywhere at finite places and one infinite place.
(So $D$ turns out Hamiltonian at $[K \colon {\Bbb Q}] -1$ infinite places.)

Then we have $D \otimes_{\Bbb Z} {\Bbb Z}_p \cong {\mathrm{M}}_2(K \otimes_{\Bbb Z} {\Bbb Z}_p)$ for any prime $p$, so we have the following isomorphism:
\begin{equation*}
D \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{{\Bbb Z}} \cong \mathrm M_2(K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{{\Bbb Z}}).
\end{equation*}

Now, we can define the Eichler order ${\cal O}_N \subset D$ of level $N$ as the following:
\begin{equation*}
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad{\cal O}_N \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{{\Bbb Z}} \cong \begin{pmatrix}\label{matrix} 
{\cal O}_K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{\Bbb Z} & {\cal O}_K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{\Bbb Z} \\
N({\cal O}_K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{\Bbb Z}) & {\cal O}_K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{\Bbb Z} \\
\end{pmatrix} \subset \mathrm M_2(K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{{\Bbb Z}}).   
\end{equation*}

It is known that any two maximal orders ${\cal O}_1, {\cal O}_2$ of $D$ is conjugate to each other, i.e., ${\cal O}_1 = t{\cal O}_2t^{-1}$ for $^{\exists} t \in D$. Now, I would like to ask

**Q.** Suppose we have two Eichler orders of level $N$ of $D$, i.e., ${\cal O}_{N,1}$, ${\cal O}_{N,2}$. Then is there $^{\exists} t \in D$ such that ${\cal O}_{N,1} = t{\cal O}_{N,2}t^{-1}$?

My idea is as follows: Keeping in mind that $D$ splits everywhere at all finite places, we have $\pi \colon D \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \widehat{\Bbb Z} \cong {\mathrm{M}}_2(K \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \widehat{\Bbb Z})$. Therefore we fix this isomorphism $\pi$. There exists a unique maximal order ${\mathrm{M}}_2({\cal O}_K \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \widehat{\Bbb Z}) \subset {\mathrm{M}}_2(K \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \widehat{\Bbb Z})$.

Then for any chosen maximal order ${\cal O}$ inside $D$, we have $\gamma \colon {\cal O} \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \widehat{\Bbb Z} \cong 
\alpha{\mathrm{M}}_2({\cal O}_K \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \widehat{\Bbb Z}){\alpha}^{-1}$, where $^{\exists}\alpha \in \operatorname{GL}_2(K \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \widehat{\Bbb Z})$. I claim that the level $N$ Eichler order ${\cal O}_N \subset {\cal O}$ is defined as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\gamma({\cal O}_N) \subset \alpha
\begin{pmatrix}
{\cal O}_K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{\Bbb Z} & {\cal O}_K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{\Bbb Z} \\
N({\cal O}_K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{\Bbb Z}) & {\cal O}_K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{\Bbb Z} \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\alpha^{-1} \subset \mathrm M_2(K \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}} \widehat{{\Bbb Z}}).   
\end{equation*}

Thus ${\cal O}_N$ is uniquely determined inside ${\cal O}$ once a maximal ordre ${\cal O}$ is chosen. We have only to compare these Eichler orders obtained from chosen maximal orders. So, we use the fact that $D$ satisfies the Eichler condition which ensures that another maximal order ${\cal O}'$ is conjugate to ${\cal O}$. I think that this fact might imply that two Eichler orders ${\cal O}_N \subset {\cal O}$ and ${\cal O}_N' \subset {\cal O}'$ will also be conjugate to each other.

Comment: There were three different notations for the matrix ring, which I thought might be an accident, so I edited them all to be the same.  I hope that this was correct.

Comment: What do you mean there exists a unique maximal order?  You can conjugate by GL(2) over the (finite) adeles.

Comment: Yes, when I say the unique, it means that two ordres are conjugate to each other as you teach me! Pierre